# installing transformers on M1 gives jax

Tags: python, pip, conda, huggingface-transformers, apple-m1

I am new to Python and trying to install transformers following instructions [here](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/installation#install-with-conda)

i did all the steps but when I got to

> python -c "from transformers import pipeline;
> print(pipeline('sentiment-analysis')('we love you'))"

I got

```
RuntimeError: This version of jaxlib was built using AVX instructions, which your CPU and/or operating system do not support. You may be able work around this issue by building jaxlib from source.
```

So I reinstalled and  installed with:

```
pip uninstall jax jaxlib
pip install --upgrade jax jaxlib
```

and got exactly the same error

Now I am on this [link](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/developer.html)

and did this:

```
pip install numpy wheel build
```

but I cannot run the next line

```
python build/build.py
pip install dist/*.whl  # installs jaxlib (includes XLA)
```

because I am getting

```
python: can't open file '/Users/e5028514/build/build.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

my mac is [image]

Answer (score 0):

The link tells you to `git clone` the jax repository first. This is why you get a "No such file or directory" error.